# Compare two large dataframes using pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am currently working on a data migration assignment, trying to compare two dataframes from two different databases using pyspark to find out the differences between two dataframes and record the results in a csv file as part of data validation. I am trying for a performance efficient solution since there are two reasons.i.e. large dataframes and table keys are unknown

```
#Approach 1 - Not sure about the performance and it is case-sensitive

df1.subtract(df2)

#Approach 2 - Creating row hash for each row in dataframe

piperdd=df1.rdd.map(lambda x: hash(x)) 
r=row("h_cd")
df1_new=piperdd.map(r).toDF()
```

The problem which I am facing in approach 2 is final dataframe(df1_new) is retrieving only hash column(h_cd) but I need all the columns of dataframe1(df1) with hash code column(h_cd) since I need to report the row difference in a csv file.Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a try with dataframes, it should be more concise.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(a, a*2, a+3) for a in range(10)], "A B C".split(' '))
#df1.show()
from pyspark.sql.functions import hash
df1.withColumn('hash_value', hash('A','B', 'C')).show()

+---+---+---+-----------+
|  A|  B|  C| hash_value|
+---+---+---+-----------+
|  0|  0|  3| 1074520899|
|  1|  2|  4|-2073566230|
|  2|  4|  5| 2060637564|
|  3|  6|  6|-1286214988|
|  4|  8|  7|-1485932991|
|  5| 10|  8| 2099126539|
|  6| 12|  9| -558961891|
|  7| 14| 10| 1692668950|
|  8| 16| 11|  708810699|
|  9| 18| 12|  -11251958|
+---+---+---+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you solution. This solution looks exactly the same which I am looking for. Problem I am facing now is when I am passing dataframe column names dynamically.  `df_columns = ','.join(map(str, df1.schema.names)) `      `df1.withColumn('hash_value', hash(df_columns)).show(5)`

Comment: I am able to fix this issue by passing column names as an array. Thank again for providing me a direction to proceed.